# Given an input as 'sentence', how to return the element that appears the most

Tags: python, python-3.x

This first function counts the string's characters

```
def character_count(sentence):
    characters = {}
    for char in sentence:
        if char in characters:
            characters[char] = characters[char] + 1
        else: 
            characters[char] = 1
    return characters
```

This second function determines the most common character and identifies which one appears most often by characters[char] which is established in the previous helper function

```
def most_common_character(sentence):
    chars = character_count(sentence)
    most_common = ""
    max_times = 0


    for curr_char in chars:
        if chars[curr_char] > max_times:
            most_common = curr_char
            max_times = chars[curr_char]
    return most_common
```

Comment: what is `sentence` currently? A string?

Comment: just use `Counter`

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply using what Python provides?

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sentence = "This is such a beautiful day, isn't it"
>>> c = Counter(sentence).most_common(3)
>>> c
[(' ', 7), ('i', 5), ('s', 4)]
```

After if you really want to proceed word by word and avoid spaces:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> sentence = "This is such a beautiful day, isn't it"
>>> res = Counter(sentence.replace(' ', ''))
>>> res.most_common(1)
[('i', 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You actually don't have to change anything! Your code will work with a list as is (the variable names just become misleading). Try it:

```
most_common_character(['this', 'is', 'a', 'a', 'list'])
```

Output:

```
'a'
```

This will work for lists with any kind of elements that are hashable (numbers, strings, characters, etc)